Every entire function $g$ such that $g' = g^2$
I ran across this neat exercise that I had to think about a little: Find every holomorphic function $g:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $g'=g^2$.
Can you check my proposed solution and maybe enlighten me, if there is a more elegant solution?
I hypothesize that only $g=0$ fulfils the requirements. Clearly, $g'=0=g^2$ in that case.
Now assume that $g$ fulfils the above requirements and there is $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $g(z_0) \neq 0$. Then, by continuity, there is a neighborhood $\varepsilon > 0$, such that $g\neq 0$ on $B_\varepsilon(z_0)$. Then,  for $z \in B_\varepsilon(z_0)$:
$$
\left( \tfrac{1}{g(z)}\right)' = -\tfrac{g'(z)}{g(z)^2} = -1
$$
Hence, $g(z) = \tfrac{1}{\frac{1}{g(z_0)}+z_0-z}$ for all $z \in B_\varepsilon(z_0)$, and by indentity theorem, $g(z) = \tfrac{1}{\frac{1}{g(z_0)}+z_0-z}$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \left \lbrace z_0 + \tfrac{1}{g(z_0)}\right \rbrace$. But this can not be extended to a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$.

Seems OK.  Alternate: find the series solutions at $z=0$, then compute the radius of convergence, which is not $\infty$.

I see. But this looks like Cauchy-product and tedious computations. Thanks

For $g \ne 0$, the differential equation $$\frac{dg}{g^2} = dz$$ has the general solution $$-\frac{1}{g} = z + c$$ that has a pole for any $c$, So $g=0$ is the only entier solution.

@HyperbolicPDEfriend: Not very tedious. Compute the first coefficients from $(n+1)a_{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k a_{n-k}$ and you should see the pattern quickly.

a variation on OP's proof makes use of the Argument Principle -- if $g$ isn't identically zero, then with $\gamma_r(t) := r \cdot \exp\big(2 \pi i \cdot t\big)$ for $t\in [0,1]$ for all but countably many $r\gt 0$ then $\int_{\gamma_r}\frac{g'}{g}=\int_{\gamma_r}g= 0$ so $g$ is non-zero and entire and so is $\frac{1}{g(z)}$ which has constant derivative hence is a degree (at most) one polynomial making $g(z)$ bounded hence constant which is impossible if $g\neq 0$.

Suppose $g$ has a zero at a point $z_0$, and let $k$ be the order of the zero.
Since $g'=g^2,$ it follows that $g'$ has a zero of order $2k$ in $z_0$, from which it follows that
$$k=\text{ord}(g,z_0)=\text{ord}(g', z_0)+1=2k+1,$$
which only makes sense if $k=\infty$, i.e.: $g\equiv 0$.
On the other hand, if $g$ is never zero then we can write it as $g=e^{h(z)}$. Differentiating we get
$$h'(z)=e^{h(z)},$$
which implies that $\left(e^{-h(z)}\right)'$ is constant, hence $g=0$.
Second solution:
Since $g'=g^2$, it follows that the spherical derivative $\rho(g)=\frac{|g'|}{1+|g|^2}$is bounded. This implies that $g$ is of exponential type, which is clearly impossible if $g'=g^2$ unless $g$ is trivial.

I believe it should say that for $z\in B_\varepsilon(z_0),$ we have $$\left(\frac{1}{g(z)}\right)'=-\frac{g'(z)}{g(z)^2}=-1.$$ I didn't follow what happened next, I'm afraid, so I can't say whether it works or not. What I would do next is note that $$\left(\frac{1}{g(z)}\right)'=-1$$ means that there is some $\zeta\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $$\frac{1}{g(z)}=-z+\zeta$$ for all $z\in B_\varepsilon(z_0),$ so $g(z)=\frac{-1}{z-\zeta}$ for all $z\in B_\varepsilon(z_0),$ which cannot be extended to an entire function due to the pole at $z=\zeta,$ thus acquiring the desired contradiction.
Edit: As Martin R points out in the comments below (and as I should have checked right away), all one needs to do to determine $\zeta$ is make the substitution $z\mapsto z_0,$ which yields $\zeta=\frac{1}{g(z_0)}+z_0,$ and so you get the exact same conclusion as you already came to.
Upshot: You had a solid idea, but it could have been justified more carefully and less messily.

An alternative approach is as follows. Let $\xi=g(0).$ Then $g'(0)=\xi^2.$ Since $$g''(z)=\frac{d}{dz}\left[g'(z)\right]=\frac{d}{dz}\left[g(z)^2\right]=2g(z)g'(z)=2g(z)^3,$$ then $g''(0)=2\xi^3.$ Continuing in this fashion, a ready proof by induction shows that $g^{(n)}(0)=n!\xi^{n+1}$ for all $n\geq 0,$ and so $\frac{g^{(n)}(0)}{n!}=\xi^{n+1}$ for all $n\geq 0.$ This tells us that the MacLaurin series for $g$ is given by $$g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\xi^{n+1}z^n.$$ Computing the radius of convergence shows that $g$ is entire if and only if $\xi=0.$

Determining $\zeta$ by setting $z=z_0$ in $\frac{1}{g(z)}=-z+\zeta$ gives $g(z) = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{g(z_0)}+z_0-z}$, which is what OP already got. Also your conclusion “cannot be extended to an entire function due to the pole ...” looks quite similar to what OP already said.

@MartinR, yeah, it had seemed like that was the direction the OP was heading. I'm dismayed that I didn't even think to check what form $\zeta$ might take relative to $z_0.$

Yes, the above argument is equal to mine, a little more clear however. The second argument is very elegant :+1:
